# Search ids in a space of 10^30

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree, brute-force

I have distributed 50 millions of ids within a numeric space of the size of 10^30. Ids are distributed randomly, no series or reversed function could be found. For example, the minimum and the maximum are:

- 25083112306903763728975529743
- 29353757632236106718171971627

Two consecutive ids have a distance in the order at least of 10^19. For example:

- 28249462572807242052513352500
- 28249462537043093417625790615

This distribution is solid to a brute force attack since to find 1 consecutive to another, it will take at least 10^19 search (to have an idea about timing, 1000 search it will take 1 second then it will spend 10^16 seconds...).

There are other search algorithms to search in this space that could take less time and make my ids distribution less solid?

Comment: can we try to using some thing like hash table hierarchy? For example, two level hash table is (1) first divide 50 millions into `N` set, each set have (50million / N) item (2) then construct hash table in each set. Using idea of hierarchy can help to accelerate searching.

Comment: But those 50 millions of ids are not known by who need to search...

Answer (score 0):

If your 50 millions are really randomly distributed in a space of 10^30, you can't do anything better than brute force.

This means you can only iterate your 10^30 values in a random order, and in average you have to test `10^30 / (5 10^7) = 2.10^22` to find one.

Of course, there exists an algorithm to find all of them at first try, but it's extremely unlikely that you stumble on it without knowing the ids first.